# Error ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ruby 2.4 and rails 5.1.6.

In order to learn RoR, I handcrafted a User model, view and controller rather than use a scaffold.

After filling in the form to create a new user I get this error in the rails server log:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-27 15:52:45 +0530
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gdSumxEvNi6ECKBZLFKN9dB/PYLOmixMcf5oYcUGkE1u4iAa/YkJlu7SJbPQNlh6J2SEzR2WeSUT9frhteEOCw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"User1", "email"=>"user1@yahoo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?  [["email", "user1@yahoo.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "User1"], ["email", "user1@yahoo.com"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$Efhs2Z2BRa5FCUdSIz6D5.c/eiFQm3JaW818veE644NdoWluRLjoq"], ["created_at", "2018-08-27 10:22:45.636574"], ["updated_at", "2018-08-27 10:22:45.636574"]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 93ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)


Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-27 15:52:45 +0530
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (9.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: 
    2: <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
    3: <h2><%= @user.email %></h2>

app/views/users/show.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___1408287096995644504_70277415453360'
```

As you can see, the record is saved to the db successfully, but somehow, the @user variable is destroyed by the time it gets to the show.html.erb template.

Here is the users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    byebug
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
      byebug
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

...and here are the contents of show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
<h2><%= @user.email %></h2>
```

The output of @user.name at the byebug breakpoint in the user#create action shows the correct value, but at the second byebug breakpoint in the user#show action, I get this error:

```
(byebug) @user.name
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Just to make sure, I made a second app, but used a scaffold generator and everything worked fine.

Any ideas?

p.s.

I wrote some validations in the user model (app/models/user.rb). I've included this below just in case...

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    before_save {email.downcase!}
    validates :email, presence: true, 
                        format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
                        uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

    validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}

    has_secure_password
end
```

Comment: `@user` is nil. Do you defined `@user` in the show action?

Comment: No. The scaffold generated code had nothing in the show action, so I left it out of mine as well.

Comment: Post the full controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the setter method in the private area of user's controller

```
private
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

and add this in the controller :

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show]
```

you may also define (in before_action) other methods that need to access the user object

Comment: This worked perfectly. In my haste, I didn't pay any attention to this code in the scaffold generated controller. I'm also marking this as the accepted answer because of its completeness even though Ravi Teja Dandu's answer also worked.

Comment: Thank you and u r welcome.
Ravi's solution works fine too but u will need to put the the same code in each action

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't defined `@user` object. You can do that by adding `@user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])` inside your `show` action

Answer (score 2):

If you can check your log below statement is mentioned:

```
Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-27 15:52:45 +0530
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
```

The hash {"id"=>"1"} indicates, You are trying to fetch user with id=1.
Now, You just have to re-define show method as below:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end
```